# Use Geany IDE On Ubuntu For Objective-c & C#

Tags: linux, c#, ubuntu, geany

Is there any IDE is available in Ubuntu for programming in C# and Objective -C . I have already one IDE called Geany installed . I want to use it for writing C# and objective -C if it is possible .

Comment: You seem to have two questions: "Is there an IDE?" and "(How) can Geany be used?" What is it that you really want to know? -- If you look for an IDE that matches your requirements, you should list your requirements in the question. If you want to extend Geany with some features (e.g., in the form of plugins), you should list what you need in your question. Please [edit] your question (be specific).

Answer (score 1):

MonoDevelop I heard is good for C# and has support for Objective-c if I remember correctly.

That being said, more details on what exactly you require from the IDE/text editor/etc. would be helpful in making a recommendation.

Comment: I need an IDE only supported by Linux  to run objective-c and  c# .    Yes MonoDevelop is obiviously a good option  for C#  but what about   objective-c  ?